# Crystal Reports formula based on group footer summary field

Tags: crystal-reports

New to Crystal Reports - 
I have a report with 3 columns - Estimated Hours, Actual Hours, Remaining Hours.
In the Group Footer it summarizes the hours by job.  The remaining hours formula is {job.esthours}-{job.actualhours}.  I want it to be blank if there is no estimated hours. I know that I can't use the sum of estimated hours in my formula but not sure what formulas to use.

[Sample Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVqBh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a condition to suppress your formula in case the first cfield value is null. You can do it in two ways:

1) Add the condition in your Remaining Hours formula. Try this if you want blank also in your detail sections. Right-Click -> Suppress -> add there the next condition:

```
if(isnull({job.esthours}))
```

2) Add the condition in your Remaining Hours Summary. This is better if you wish to show negative values of Remaining Values in your Details Section for some reason. Right-Click -> Suppress -> add there the next condition:

```
if(isnull(sum({job.esthours})))
```

And yes, you can use the estimated hours summary, , you can find it in your Formula workshop, in the Report Fields tree

Comment: Thank you.  The suppression worked, however I didn't need to use "if" before the statement.